# How to the details of supplementary Group ID in Unix

Tags: unix, aix

I'm using Unix AIX.  Is there a way to find out the details of the permissions that Supplementary Group ID has access to?  (ie read only permissions to a given directory) I understand that the members of the group have the same access. How do I trace what the specific permissions are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "aclget" command will show you the both the normal unix group ownership w/ permissions as well as any extended permissions that might apply to additional groups.